# @click in vuejs component will not react in any way

Tags: javascript, vue.js, click, components

```
<template>
 <div class="container" id="app">
     <button @click="console.log('hello')">
         Hello
     </button>
 </div>
</template>

<script>
 export default {
     name:"test",
 }
</script>

<style scoped>
</style>
```

This is just an example code for vuejs component and all I want is to have "hello" written on my console every time I click on button but this doesn't seem to work and I do not understand why... I have tried to use @click in a more complicated component and when I realized it didn't work i wanted to make a new component that only had this button so I could eliminate the possibility that the rest of the code was causing this... I don't get any errors or warnings... I have no idea what is happening...

Answer (score 0):

Try it the way, it's described in the documentation by adding a method in the script block and refer to that method:

```
<template>
   <div class="container" id="app">
     <button @click="log('hallo')">
         Hello
     </button>
 </div>
</template>


<script>
export default {
    data() {
        return {

        }
    },
    methods: {
        log(text) {
            console.log(text)
        }
    }
}
</script>
```

It's a good practise to add the .prevent to the @click notation to prevent the default behaviour like a post / refresh

```
@click.prevent="myFunction"
```

Comment: Yeah I tried doing that in the first place but it doesn't seem to work... It does not give any errors but it also doesn't do anything...

Comment: do you use it as a SPA? (in a single file)
Show me your code where your component is being loaded. Have you registered it as a component etc?

Comment: Yeah im using it only in my test.blade.php file and i have registered it globally in my app.js file... This is how my test.blade.php file looks like..
`@extends('layouts.app') 

@section('content')
<div class="container">
    <test></test>

</div>
@endsection`

Answer (score 0):

You should definitely be getting an error.

The reason it's not working though is everything you use in the template is essentially prefixed with `this` so your code is trying to call `this.console.log` which doesn't exist.

I typically have a global mixin method called `log` that logs whatever arguments are passed to it.

```
Vue.mixin({
  methods: {
    log () {
      if (console && process.env.NODE_ENV !== 'production') {
        console.log(...arguments)
      }
    },
  },
})
```